# Page not found in Laravel production

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

In my web.php file, i have a the below route and it works fine

```
Route::get('users/xml', function() {
    $merchants = DB::table('merchants')->where('published', '1')->get();

    $xml = new XMLWriter();
    $xml->openMemory();
    $xml->startDocument();
    $xml->startElement('markers');
    foreach($merchants as $merchant) {
        $xml->startElement('marker');
        $xml->writeAttribute('id', $merchant->id);
        $xml->writeAttribute('name', $merchant->merchant_code);
        $xml->writeAttribute('address', $merchant->address);
        $xml->writeAttribute('lat', $merchant->lat);
        $xml->writeAttribute('lng', $merchant->lng);
        $xml->endElement();
    }
    $xml->endElement();
    $xml->endDocument();

    $content = $xml->outputMemory();
    /*File::put(storage_path().'/file.xml', $content);*/
    return response($content)->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
});
```

However, when i push my code to production(Nginx), the page is not found.

Comment: Is it the only page that is not found? Is the home page showing `/`?

Comment: Put all the logic and code in the `route` file is not a good method.

Comment: Your logic belongs in a Controller not the Routes folder / files.

Comment: It seems like the problem is with your website configuration in nginx, not in the routing itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution in the laravel.log file!
The reason why it is not loading is because the class XMLWriter is not bundled with the php server on Vultr(Nginx).
So i went to the terminal and typed

```
yum install php-xml
```

Voila, it works!